# Asp.Net Core Controller - Why ObjectResult classes are not typed?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

The following method compiles just fine and I would much rather this be a compile error:

```
    [HttpGet("some/route")]
    public ActionResult<string> GetSomething()
    {
        return Ok(23);
    }
```

`string` and `int` are incompatible, but this compiles just fine. When using tools like Swagger (Open API), they generate endpoint definitions that are not correct.

I was wondering why `ObjectResult` classes are not typed? Moreover, is there a workaround to this problem?

Edit:
I am trying to avoid bugs when swagger definition claims that a `string` is returned, but instead, you actually get an `int`. If `int`s and `string`s don't make sense, then imagine two random JSON objects `DtoA` and `DtoB`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the response doesn't contains int and string type. The response body's type is text/plain, application/json  or else.

So there is no need to check the int or string in `OkObjectResult`'s `ActionResultObjectValue` value. Normally, there will all convert into string or byte as the
response content.

Besides, the swagger will generate the generate endpoint definitions according to the
`ActionResult<Tvalue>`'s Tvalue type.

If you return  `public ActionResult<int> GetSomething()`, you will find the result will convert into `int`.

[image]

---

Update:

OkObjectResult inherits the ActionResult. The returned child class does not impact the Parent class compilation.This is by design.

`ActionResult<T>` enables you to return a type deriving from `ActionResult` or return a specific type.

To enforce compile error,you could just return int which is a specific type. And you could see the error message appear when you return `int`.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to avoid bugs, when I return `int` in the OK `ObjectResult`, but the method definition claims that it returns `ActionResult<string>`. If `int`s and `string`s don't make sense, then replace them with random objects `DtoA` and `DtoB`